# How to design divider Textfield in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to design `textfield` in flutter like this

[image]

Comment: i suggest use some pacakges for this try  this package `https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields`@Laila Mattar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/code_field) which can create basically same result as in picture.

Answer (score 3):

Did you saw [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields)? It has many styling options.